# Chain inheritance in abstract classes with multiple generic typed parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Firstly, let's lay down what I have that is working prior to the question at hand.

Assume two abstract classes such as these already exist:

```
public abstract class BaseApiController<T> : ApiController where T : ApiController

public abstract class BaseLibraryController<T, M> : BaseApiController<T>
    where T : ApiController
    where M : ITrackedCommandMessage
```

and so does an API controller such as the following:

```
public class LibraryController : BaseLibraryController<BaseApiController<LibraryController>, VideoLibraryMessage>
```

My goal is to provide the LibraryController (and other ASP.NET Web API controllers so it's gotta be reusable) with new (and different in business context compared to BaseLibraryController) functionality while retaining the functionality available to it through the BaseLibraryController inheritance.

What I've tried so far is to create an additional abstract class such as this:

```
public abstract class BaseFolderController<T> : BaseApiController<T> 
    where T : ApiController
```

which implements the new functionality in question and then modify the BaseLibraryController to inherit from it as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseLibraryController<T, M> : BaseFolderController<T>
    where T : BaseApiController<T>
    where M : ITrackedCommandMessage
```

as well as change the LibraryController to try and facilitate these changes above:

```
public class LibraryController :
    BaseLibraryController<BaseFolderController<BaseApiController<LibraryController>>,
        VideoLibraryMessage>
```

alas that's where the compiler throws the following error:

```
BaseFolderController<BaseApiController<LibraryController>> cannot be used as type parameter T, there's no implicit reference conversion from BaseFolderController<BaseApiController<LibraryController>> to BaseApiController<BaseFolderController<BaseApiController<LibraryController>>>
```

While the error message is pretty descriptive, I haven't so far been able to understand both why this wouldn't work with the syntax I tried as well as how to modify the syntax to make it work.

Note that I am not even sure that an additional abstract class is the correct design choice here, perhaps there's a better (and possibly easier?) way to achieve the stated goal so I'm open to design suggestions as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Stated about halfway through my post: "My goal is to provide the LibraryController (and other ASP.NET Web API controllers so it's gotta be reusable) with new (and different in business context compared to BaseLibraryController) functionality while retaining the functionality available to it through the BaseLibraryController inheritance."

Comment: I think the problem is the generic type parameter for the controller. Why not just `BaseApiController : ApiController`?